# Setting up WebGL and WebPlayer for simple hybrid deployment

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

In https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/canvas is a section telling about hybrid deployment. It also contains a chunk of code and say that it is needed to create a new Pre-Loader that will decide which build to redirect to. However, I can't properly find out how shall I name the file to copy the code and where to save it (i.e. in the build, where is html file or in Assets folder before building the project)?

Another thing is how to set up "Settings" "Facebook Canvas" section, where I use Unity binary URL? Lets say I store my .unity3d file on Dropbox and building up WebGL version separately. Shall I upload all WebGL build files in the same directory on Dropbox, where I have .unity3d file?

Comment: After some time of tweaking I managed to implement this hybrid deployment for my project https://apps.facebook.com/tales_of_eightrivers . The key idea here was that this pre-loader is just a separate html file and secure url in Facebook Dashboard should contain URL to this pre-loader. I will make soon one-to several tutorials about how I upgraded from v6.x to 7x and set this to work in hybrid way.

Comment: So here is long awaited tutorial, which covers wide range of things how to get new Facebook game working online: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zz4uaW_9NfM